# Tabulator: Update column definition after data is loaded

Tags: tabulator

I am using autoColumns: true and data loaded through the builtin ajax call ajaxURL: "/...".  After data is loaded I would like to dynamically update a few columns to allow dropdowns to be used.   I know I could pre-define the column definitions prior to loading data but I am trying to do this dynamically.

In the code example below, I am adding new columns after data is loaded dynamically through a razor loop.  This builds select lists dynamically and I used it as a POC to test part of what I need to do with updating column definitions.

How do I replace an existing columns definition and trigger an update without replacing the cells below data?

After the column definition is updated while keeping data how do I make sure the editor "select" is set to the cell value, my thinking this would happen automatically after the definition is updated.

Thanks!

```
dataLoaded: function(data) {
 /////////////////////////////////////////
 // Example, adding dynamic columns
 /////////////////////////////////////////
 @foreach(var item in Model.Report.ReportFields) {

  <text>
   table.addColumn({
    title: "@item.FieldName",
    field: "@item.FieldName",
    editor: "select",
    editorParams: {
     values: {
      @foreach(var fi in item.ReportFieldItems) {
       <text> "@fi.ItemValue": "@fi.ItemName", </text>
      }
     }
    }
   }); 
  </text>
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Example updating column definition for field name "Status"
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 var aColumns = table.getColumns();
 for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
  if (aColumns[i]._column.field == 'Status') {
   console.log(aColumns[i]._column.defitions);
   aColumns[i]._column.definition.editor = "select";

   var obj = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
   };

   var obj2 = {
    values: obj
   };
   aColumns[i]._column.definition.editorParams = obj2;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

table.setColumns is my friend.  Before I could use this I needed to build the column definition from the returned column data.  Seems like an opportunity for a new feature instead of a quick loop to do this directly.  This answers both questions, first to update an existing definition and to not replace the existing data.

```
                var newColumns = [];
                var aColumns = table.getColumns();
                for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
                    if (aColumns[i]._column.field == 'Status') {
                        console.log(aColumns[i]._column.defitions);
                        aColumns[i]._column.definition.editor = "select";

                        var obj = {
                            key1: "value1",
                            key2: "value2"
                        };

                        var obj2 = {
                            values: obj
                        };
                        aColumns[i]._column.definition.editorParams = obj2;
                    }
                    newColumns.push(aColumns[i]._column.definition);
                }
                console.log(newColumns);
                table.setColumns(newColumns);
```

Comment: Also found in tabulator docs but my initial searches didn't find it.  The docs didn't describe how to get the existing definitions so I had to hunt the return from the table.getColumns(); function to find it and build it through iterations.   See "Replace Column Definitions" http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/columns